# NoReverse Match at Delete View

Tags: python, django

I started coding with Python and Django last week and now I start getting desperate about it.
I have to work on a To-Do-List and want to delete ToDo task by clicking on a button next to the task.
Now I always get a

> NoReverseMatch at /delete/1

error :(

The delete_confirm.html:

```
{% extends "base_page.html" %}

{% block title %}Confirm Todo delete{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from todolist import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^add', views.AddView.as_view(), name='add'),
    url(r'^impressum', views.ImpressumView.as_view(), name='impressum'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.UpdateView.as_view(), name='todo_edit'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)', views.DeleteView.as_view(), name='todo_delete'), 
)
```

The views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from todolist.models import Todo

# Create your views here.
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    model = Todo

class ImpressumView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'impressum.html'

class AddView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'add.html'
    model = Todo
    fields = ['title','deadline','progress']
    success_url = '/'

class UpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'edit.html'
    model = Todo
    fields = ['title','deadline','progress']
    success_url = '/'

class DeleteView(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'delete_confirm.html'
    model = Todo
    success_url = reverse_lazy('/')
```

The interesting part of the index.html:

```
<!--Table content-->
            {% for todo in object_list %}
            <tr>
              <td class="text-left">{{todo.title}}</td>
              <td> {{todo.deadline}}</td>
              <td>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{todo.progress}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{todo.progress}}%">
                    {{todo.progress}}%
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td >
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <a href="edit/{{todo.id}}" role="button" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
                  <a href="delete/{{todo.id}}" role="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete</a>
                  <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Done?" data-placement="right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></button>
                </div>
              </td>
          {% endfor %}
```

Would be great if some of your guys could help a newbie :)

Comment: For future questions, please provide the full traceback, it will contain useful information like the line on which the error occurred.

Comment: As an aside, it would be better to use the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag e.g. `{% url 'todo_edit' todo.id %}` and `{% url 'todo_delete' todo.id %}` instead of hardcoding the urls and `edit/{{todo.id}}` and `delete/{{todo.id}}` in your template.

Comment: if you don't mind please update your question with the full error traceback given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line in your delete view.

```
class DeleteView(DeleteView):
    ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('/')
```

You can either provide the url:

```
success_url = '/'
```

or use `reverse_lazy` with the url name that you wish to reverse:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Comment: Perfectly, it works! :)
But could you explain the error to me? I get it really often but I didn't find any site where it was explained easy

Comment: `reverse_lazy` takes the name of a url pattern, e.g. `index`, and returns the url that matches it e.g. `'/'`. It can also take optional parameters for the url. If Django cannot find a url that matches, it raises a `NoReverseMatch` exception. You got this because you used `reverse_lazy` with `'/'` instead of `'index'`.